# Load More Button Issue in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-database

I have created an quote application with list adapter filled from a database. It has a load more button with the 15 items threshhold. It is not showing if the quote size is below 15, but It's showing if the list is 15 and when we press load more button it crashes.

```
final Button btnLoadMore=new Button(this);
            btnLoadMore.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#351802"));
            btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e8d8a7"));
            btnLoadMore.setTypeface(btnLoadMore.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            btnLoadMore.setText("Load More Status");


            if(c.getCount()<15){

            }

            else{
                 list.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);}
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            anifadein=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slidedown);
            list.startAnimation(anifadein);

            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    map = quotesList.get(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuotesActivity.this,
                            QuoteDialogActivity.class);
                    int itemPosition     = position;
                    if(startingPoint>=30){


                        intent.putExtra("Pos", itemPosition+1);
                        intent.putExtra("LstCount", list.getCount()-1);
                    }else{
                        intent.putExtra("Pos", itemPosition+1);
                        intent.putExtra("LstCount", list.getCount());}
                    intent.putExtra("QuoteId", map.get(KEY_ID));
                    intent.putExtra("quotesType", quType);
                    intent.putExtra("startFrom", getIntent().getStringExtra("startFrom"));
                    intent.putExtra("Quotes", quotesList);
            //  Log.i("COUNT",""+(itemPosition+1)+"-"+list.getCount());
                    intent.putExtra("Fav", map.get(KEY_FAVORITE));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitial.show();
                    }

                }
            });

             btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        if(btnLoadMore.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                        Cursor newC = null;

                        if (quType != 0) {

                            switch (quType) {
                            case 1:


                                    newC = db.getQuotes(""+startingPoint);


                                break;
                            case 2:
                                newC = db.getFavoriteQuotes(""+startingPoint);
                                //page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                newC = db.getAuthorQuotes(getIntent().getStringExtra("AuthorId"),""+startingPoint);
                            //  page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        // Starting a new async task
                        if(newC.getCount()<15){
                            btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                        startingPoint+=15;  
                        do{
                            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
                            map.put(KEY_ID, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                            map.put(KEY_TEXT, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT)));
                            map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_AUTHOR)));
                            map.put(KEY_PICTURE, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_PICTURE)));
                            map.put(KEY_PICTURE_SDCARD, String.valueOf(newC.getInt(newC
                                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PICTURE_SDCARD))));
                            map.put(KEY_WEB_ID,
                                    String.valueOf(newC.getInt(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB_ID))));
                            //Log.i("web_id",String.valueOf(newC.getInt(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                            map.put(KEY_FAVORITE, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_FAVORITE)));

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            quotesList.add(map);
                            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                                mInterstitial.show();
                            }

                        } while (newC.moveToNext());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  }}
                });
        }
    }
```

Log Cat is here

```html
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325): Process: com.karopass.hindi_suvichar, PID: 22325
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at com.karopass.hindi_suvichar.QuotesActivity$2.onClick(QuotesActivity.java:242)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
02-29 16:39:50.553: E/AndroidRuntime(22325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the logcat of the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<=` which means Less than or Equal to ie `if(c.getCount()<=15){`

Alternately you could do (without an else clause).

```
if(c.getCount() > 15( { 
    btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ........ your code that is currently in the else clause.. 
} else {
    btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}
```

Note! View.GONE is an alternative to View.INVISIBLE. The difference being that INVISIBLE just makes it so that the view (Button) cannot be seen, whilst GONE makes it if as the view (Button) is not there.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for suggestion, but button does not showing if I use code that You have written

Comment: Amended the answer to shor or hide the button dependent upon the c.getCount().

Comment: I think you need to add the button to the layout. Something like `<layout>.addView(btnLoadMore)` after `btnLoadMore.setText("Load More Status");`